# Functional programming equivalents for the following

Tags: scala, design-patterns, clojure, functional-programming

I am trying to make the leap from functional programs for "hello world" equivalents to more real-world applications.

As I come from a Java world and have been exposed to all it's design patterns, my modeling process is still very Java oriented (e.g. I think in terms of *Managers, *Factory, *ClientFactory, *Handler etc.)

Changing my thought process in one shot, will be hard so I was hoping to get some pointers on how the following scenarios (described in a OO way) would be modeled in a functional language.

Examples in a functional language like Clojure/Haskell (or perhaps a hybrid like Scala) would be helpful.

**Stateless Request handlers**

E.g. is a Servlet. It is essentially a request handler with methods like doGet, doPost. How would one model such a class in a functional language?

**Orchestrator classes**

Such classes don't do anything by themselves, but just orchestrate the whole process or workflow. They offer multiple entry point APIs.

E.g. A OrderOrchestrator orchestrates a multiple step workflow starting with payment instrument validation, shopping cart management, payment, shipment initiation etc.

They might maintain some internal state of their own that is used by the different steps like payment, shipment etc.

**ClientFactory pattern**

Let's say you have written a client that for a LogService that is used by your client to log traffic data about their services. The client logs the data in S3 under buckets and accounts managed by you and you provide additional services like reporting and analytics on this data.
You don't want your customer to worry about providing the configuration information like AWS account info etc and hence you provide a ClientFactory that instantiates the appropriate client object based on whether this is for testing or production purposes without requiring the customer to provide any configuration. E.g. LogServiceClientFactory.getProdInstance() or LogServiceClientFactory.getTestInstance().

How is such a client modeled in a functional language?

**Builder Pattern and other Fluent API designs**

Client libraries often provide Builders to create objects with complex configuration. Sometimes APIs are also fluent to make it easy to create. An example of Fluent API is Mockito APIs : Mockito.when(A.get()).thenReturn(a) IIRC this is internally implemented by returning progressively restrictive Builders to allow the developer to write this code.

Is this a parallel to this in the functional programming world?

**Datastore instances**

Let's say that your codebase uses data stored in a ActiveUserRegistry from multiple places. You want only 1 instance of this registry to exist and have the entire code base access this registry. So you provide a ActiveUserRegistry.getInstance() that guarantees that all the code base accesses the instance (Assume that the instance is thread-safe etc.)

How is this managed in a functional setting? Do we have to make sure the same instance is passed around in the entire codebase?

Comment: This can help describe some of the design patterns in the functional world: http://norvig.com/design-patterns/

Answer (score 2):

Below is something to get started:

**Stateless Request handlers**

Clojure: Protocols

Haskell: Type classes

**Orchestrator classes**

State monad

**ClientFactory pattern**

LogServiceClientFactory is a Module and getProdInstance and getTestInstance being the functions in the module.

**Builder Pattern and other Fluent API designs**

Function composition

**Datastore instances**

Clojure: Function that uses an atom (to store and use the single instance)

Haskell: TVar,MVar

Answer (score 2):

I'm not vary familiar with the many of these Java-style structures, but I'll take a stab at answering:

**Stateless Request handlers**

These exist in the functional world as well. Functions can fill this role easily, even with something as simple as a function from requests to responses. The Play Framework uses something more powerful, specifically a function from the `Request` to an `Iteratee` (type `(RequestHeader) ⇒ Iteratee[Array[Byte], SimpleResult]`). The `Iteratee` is an entity that can progressively consume input (`Array[Byte]`) as it is received and eventually produce the response (`SimpleResult`) to give back to the client. The request handler function is stateless and can be reused. The `Iteratee` is also stateless -  the result of feeding it each chunk is actually to get a new `Iteratee` back, which is then fed the next chunk. (I'm oversimplifying really, it uses Futures, is entirely non-blocking, and has effective error handling - worth looking at to get a feel of the power and simplicity that functional-style code can bring to this problem).

**Orchestrator classes**

I'm not familiar with this pattern, so forgive me if this makes no sense. Having one giant mutable object that gets passed around is an anti-pattern. In functional code, there would be separate datatypes to represent the data that needs to passed between each stage of the process. These datatypes would be immutable.

As for things that organize other things, look at Akka and how one actor can monitor other actors underneath it, handling errors or restarting them as needed.

**Builder Pattern and other Fluent API designs**

Functional program has these and takes them to their logical conclusion. Functional code allows for very powerful DSLs. As for an example, check out a parser combinator library, either the one in the Scala standard library or one of the libraries for Haskell.

**ClientFactory pattern and Datastore instances**

I don't think this is any different in functional code. Either you have a singleton, or you do proper dependency injection. The Factory pattern is used in functional code as well, though first-class functions make many design patterns too trivial to be worth naming (from the GoF: Factory, Factory method, Command, and at least some instances of Strategy and Template can usually just be functions).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Functional Programming Patterns in Scala and Clojure: http://pragprog.com/book/mbfpp/functional-programming-patterns-in-scala-and-clojure .

It should exactly have what you need.